# How to sort data in graphQl with apollo server?

Tags: node.js, sorting, apollo, graphql-js

I use apollo-server to write a graphql code. before send data I want to  do some sort  on data based on optional fields and filters, and I need to know right way to write my code? 
Is there a method in graphql to automatically sort my data?

I used [lodash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash) for sort and I think they are not optimized
after I searched
I saw [prisma](https://www.howtographql.com/graphql-js/8-filtering-pagination-and-sorting/) but my data is returned by another api not in database.
I need somthing like prisma.

my code something like this
I want to sort book base on name or lastName in query
but in real book objects returned by an api.

```
const { ApolloServer, gql, } = require('apollo-server');

const books = [
{
    title: 'Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets',
    authors: [{"name":"a1", "lastName":"aa1"},{"name":"b1", "lastName":"bb1"},{"name":"c1", "lastName":"cc1"}]
  },
  {
    title: 'Jurassic Park',
    authors: [{"name":"a" ,"lastName":"aa"},{"name":"b", "lastName":"bb"},{"name":"c", "lastName":"cc"}]
  },
];
const typeDefs = gql`

type Book {
    title: String
    authors: [Author]
  }
type Query{
    books: [Book]
  }
type Author{
name: String
lastName: String
}
  `;
const resolvers = {
  Query: 
  {
    books: () => books,
// in real this book return by an api !

  },
};
const server = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers });

server.listen({port: 3002, path: '/graphql'}).then(({ url }) => {
  console.log(`  Server ready at ${url}`);
});
```

Is there a function In graphql?

Comment: is it better to do sort in client side or server side?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no possibilities to sort, order, or to do whatever filtering with graphql alone. You need to implement the sorting by yourself or with a ORM (make a method that does that), then hook that logic on a resolver that will execute the resolver method that you provided.